# how to find derivative of an array of numbers

Tags: arrays, derivative

I need help in finding derivative of single array consisting on [1111222221111122222] 
need how to get derivative of 1, -1 and 0 from above ? iam using numpy. i need some help in logic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the problem in detail, but maybe you can use [`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) or [`numpy.gradient`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html).

Comment: I have an array with [111111122222221111112222221111111112222111122221111122211111222211]  need to determine Every time the derivative is 1,
- Every time it's -1, the other way.
- Every time it's 0,